# If the number of persons per car is a random variable $H$ with mean $4$ and variance $2$, what is $P(\bar H\geq 5)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

The question is as follows:

> According to a transportation safety board, the number of persons per car passing
>   a certain intersection between 8:00 and 9:00am, is a random variable $H$ with mean $4$ and variance $2$.
>
> For a random sample of $30$ cars at this intersection during this time period, what is the probability that the average number of persons per car is at least $5$?

I've figured out that I'll be using the Central Limit Theorem to solve this, and thus far have found that:
$$P(H > 5) = 1 - P( H \leq  5).$$

But I can't seem to incorporate the sample of $30$ cars in my equation, this would only be true for a sample $n$ of $1$ car.

How can I work from here?

Comment: Normal approximation for a sample mean of $30$ is going to be horrible in this case.

Comment: @A.S.: Depends on what you mean by horrible, but yeah, it can be off by quite a bit!

Comment: @Brian By horrible, I mean that given that majority of cars hold 5 people max (7 for minivans/some SUVs) and majority of cars travel with at most 2-3 people in rush hour, so to get mean $4$, variance $2$, one must have included at least a few (school?) buses which would introduces a huge skew which is not going away after a meager $30$ samples (skew $\propto n^{-1/2}$). Only a Chebyshev bound should be given in this case - possibly improved by incorporating the info I listed above - as an upper bound and CLT as a (meaningless due to its size) lower bound.

Comment: I don't believe that anything near a school bus is needed to have variance $2$ on mean $4$ (see my comment on André Nicolas's answer), but otherwise I agree with your observation.  I do think that this question is probably a textbook one on CLT, though, and (a) the rigorous approach you suggest is probably out of scope for the student, and (b) criticism should be directed perhaps at the author.  (It would have been fine if $5$ had been replaced by, say, $4.2$.)

Comment: Well, if we do restrict ourselves to cars ($\le 5$ passagers), then we get a 2-parameter family $a_5=1-a_2-3a_1,a_3=1-3a_2-6a_1, a_4=8a_1+3a_2-1$ which yields a max skew of $-\sqrt 2$ for $a_1=\frac 1 6$, yielding a skew of $\approx -\frac 1 4$ for the average of $30$. Not too high, but still not that close to normal. The main critisism is indeed in a poor match between numbers/description and asking for a far-tail estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we can proceed as follows.

Presumably, we have that $H_1,\dotsc,H_{30}$ are iid with $E[H_i] = 4$, and $V(H_i) = 2$.

Notice that the average is
$$\bar H = \frac{H_1+\dotsb+H_{30}}{30}$$
and hence the question asks to find $P(\bar H\geq 5)$.
So, we compute
$$E[\bar H] = E\left[\frac{H_1+\dotsb+H_{30}}{30}\right] = \frac{1}{30}(E[H_1]+\dotsb+E[H_{30}]) = \frac{1}{30}\cdot 30 E[H_1] = 4$$
and similarly, by independence,
$$V(\bar H) = \frac{1}{30^2}(V(H_1)+\dotsb+V(H_{30})) = \frac{1}{30^2}\cdot30\cdot 2 = \frac{2}{30}.$$

Now, we proceed as usual
$$P(\bar H\geq 5) \approx P\left(Z\geq \frac{5-4}{\sqrt{2/30}}\right) = 1- P\left(Z< \frac{5-4}{\sqrt{2/30}}\right) = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{5-4}{\sqrt{2/30}}\right)$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal, and $\Phi$ is the usual cdf function of $Z$.

Comment: Which in this case would basically be ~0?

Comment: Yes, you might be able to say that this is virtually $0$, or just give them some digits (0.0000538).

Comment: @X1XX: It's certainly very small, but it's not zero, and in many applications, the order of magnitude of the probability would be important.  (I.e., the difference between, say, $10^{-4}$ and $10^{-5}$ would be significant.)

Comment: @X1XX I agree with Brian. My comment is from the perspective regarding a typical exercise.

Comment: @X1XX: However, see the concluding remark in André Nicolas's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to look at it a different way, you can treat the *sum* of the people in the $30$ cars as the random variable, which has mean $30 \times 4 = 120$ and variance $30 \times 2 = 60$.  It therefore has standard deviation $\sqrt{60} \doteq 7.75$.

A mean of $5$ implies a total of $150$ or more people in the $30$ cars, which gives

$$
Z = \frac{150-120}{\sqrt{60}} = \sqrt{15} \doteq 3.87
$$

and you can now proceed as in the other answers.

Comment: Sweet. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_1$ be the number of people in the first car in the sample, $H_2$ the number of people in the second car, and so on up to $H_{30}$.

Let $X=\frac{1}{30}(H_1+H_2+\cdots+H_{30})$. Then random variable $X$ is the average number of people per car in the sample.

We want the probability that $X\ge 5$. Note that $X$ has mean $4$ and variance $2/30$.

Since $X$ is a sum of a not too tiny number of identically distributed random variables, it is not too unreasonable to assume that $X$ has a not far from normal distribution.

So we want to find the probability that a normally distributed random variable with mean $4$ and variance $\frac{2}{15}$ is $\ge 5$. I expect you have computed this sort of probability a number of times.

*Remark:* The normal approximation will give that the probability is close to $0$. The estimate should not be taken entirely seriously, since the approximation error of $X$ by a normal is undoubtedly greater than the small number we obtained.

Comment: This Remark is important!  The exact difference depends on the distribution of people per car, but to give a general idea, suppose that there are either $3$ people with probability $2/3$ or $6$ people with probability $1/3$ (this yields a mean of $4$ and a variance of $2$).  Then the probability that there are at least $5$ people on average over $30$ cars is $0.000194$, of which $0.000149$ is due solely to the probability of exactly $150$ people in the $30$ cars.  Even if we account for that by taking out half of $0.000149$, we get $0.000119$—twice the value from the normal approximation.

Comment: And +1 therefore.

Comment: @Brian If we assume that there are no cars with more than $5$ people in it (most common interpretation of a "car" vs truck, SUV, minivan), the problem becomes easily. $a_5\in [\frac 1 2,\frac 2 3]$, hence $p=a_5^{30}\in[9.3\cdot 10^{-10},5.2\cdot 10^{-6}]$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the Central Limit Theorem is that the if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ (with $n$ "large enough") are random variables with the same distribution, and $E(X)=\mu$ and $Var(X)=\sigma^2$, then the new random variable $Z=\dfrac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ has normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

In your case, you have $H_1,\ldots,H_{30}$ with the same distribution, $\mu=4$, $\sigma=\sqrt{2}$ and you do

$$P(\overline{H}\geq 5)=P\left(\dfrac{\overline{H}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\geq \dfrac{5-4}{\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{30}}\right)=P(Z\geq 3.87)$$ and it is the last probability the one that you look either on a table of values for the normal distribution, or in some software that you might know.